# Json response to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The data is inserted and i receive in console the json response but the page move for the insert php and gives the json response
So i start in page A (form) and after submit moves to page B (insert)giving me the json response.
I'm having a problem getting the response of the following php into ajax

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

$target_path = "/uploads/" . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ebspma_paad_ebspma`.`formacoes`(idescola, nome, inicio, horas, local, destinatarios, dataLimite, visto, path) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,?, ?, ?, ? )";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stmt->bind_param('issssssis', $escola, $form, $data, $horas, $local, $dest, $datas, $visto, $target_path);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Opppss...A formação não foi gravada'));
}
} else {
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Opppss...A formação não foi gravada'));
}
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Nova formação gravada'));
```

This is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'nova_formacaoBD.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#ajaxDivOk').html('Informação: Esta formação foi registada na base de dados');
                if(data.status == "success"){ 
                   $('#ajaxDivOk').append(data.message);
                }
             }
          });
```

And this is my form

```
 <form action="nova_formacaoBD.php" method="post" id="formacao" name="formacao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

UPDATE

The data is all the input fields in the form

Seven strings and upload of one file

```
 <form method="post" id="formacao" name="formacao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputFile">Escola: </label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="escola" name="escola" onchange="verificaEscola()">
                            <?php echo $escolaOptions; ?>
                        </select>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome Formação: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="form" name="form" onchange="verificaNome()">
                        </input>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Data de Início: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" onchange="verificaData()" />
        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Horas: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="horas" name="horas"  onchange="verificaHoras()">
        </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Local: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="local" name="local" onchange="verificaLocal()">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Destinatários: </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="dest" name="dest" onchange="verificaDest()">
                        </input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Data Limite: </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="datas" name="datas" onchange="verificaDataLimite()"/>
        </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="exampleInputFile">Programa da Formação</label>
                       <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">
                    </div>          

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return checkBoxes(this)">Registar</button>
                </form>
```

This is my form complete

**UPDATE 2 (now it works** but i have a warning in my console 
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

and the beforeSend funtion doesn't work
I don't see the div "Wait while updating the file)
Js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formacao").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //grab all form data  
              var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'nova_formacaoBD.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function(data){
                    $('#ajaxDivAlert').html('A carregar o ficheiro...aguarde por favor')
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data.status;
                    console.log(result);
                    if(result == 'success'){
                        $('#ajaxDivAlert').empty();
                        $('#ajaxDivOk').html('Informação: ' + data.message);   
                        $("#ajaxDivOk").fadeIn(); 
                        $("#ajaxDivOk").fadeOut(5000);
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                   $("#ajaxDivErro").html('Esta formação já está registada na base de dados');
                   $("#ajaxDivErro").fadeIn();
                   $("#ajaxDivErro").fadeOut(5000);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

So, i just need to put info to complete the code, the rest is working

Comment: *I'm having a problem getting the response of the following php into ajax* - What is the problem?

Comment: How do you trigger your AJAX? Sounds like you're not preventing the default action.

Comment: Seems i don't...how can i do it? The form call the php file to insert then i was expecting to get the response from ajax to div.

Comment: `$("#formacao").on("submit", function(e){ e.preventDefault()};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some changes to do :

Html : Remove the **`action="nova_formacaoBD.php"`** like that :

```
 <form method="post" id="formacao" name="formacao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then I suppose that you have a ajax called like that :

**UPDATE**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formacao").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var ajaxDivAlert = $('#ajaxDivAlert');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'nova_formacaoBD.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                ajaxDivAlert.empty().html('A carregar o ficheiro...aguarde por favor')
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            var result = data.status;
            if (result == 'success'){
                ajaxDivAlert.empty().fadeIn().html('Informação: ' + data.message).fadeOut(5000);
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            ajaxDivAlert.empty().fadeIn().html('Esta formação já está registada na base de dados').fadeOut(5000);
        });
    });
});
```

You had the error `XMLHttpRequest` because you put `async: false`. I removed it because **`since jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($ .Deferred) is deprecated`**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I used this code but nothing is inserted into my database, even the file 'nova_formacaoBD.php' is not called. Using Fidler web debugger and that file is not called

Comment: Zlen...no the answer is not correct. The file 'nova_formacaoBD.php' is not called..and i have an error saying..the global variable "data" is  not declared...so the ajax doesn't collect the form data

Comment: That makes sense, you do not tell us what was in the data variable !! I made an edit of my post

Comment: Hi Zlen, thanks again. I made an update to my post, check the it. I put my form

Comment: Is is unclear yet. Please edit your post by writing the whole js code

Comment: Hi Zlen...made the update now. It works with some warnings and i can't get the beforeSend function to show div, the rest is working. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you Zlen. You made it. It is now working like i want. Best regards